# Unable to load shared library 'Kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems

Tags: c#, .net-core, log4net

Hello friends I have the following problem when trying to run my application in Linux Ubuntu x64, my application is written in Net Core C # with listening socket.

my code is net core 3.1:

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Teltonika.Codec;

namespace UdpListener
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
        static void Main()
        {
            Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            IPAddress ip;
            if (!IPAddress.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ipAddress"], out ip))
            {
                Log.Error("Ip is not valid.");
                throw new ArgumentException("Ip is not valid.");
            }

            int port;
            if (!int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"], out port))
            {
                Log.Error("Port is not valid.");
                throw new ArgumentException("Port is not valid.");
            }

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var udpClient = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(ip, port)))
                    {
                        Log.Info("Listening...");

                        while (true)
                        {
                            //IPEndPoint object will allow us to read datagrams sent from any source.
                                var receivedResults = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();

                            byte[] data = receivedResults.Buffer;


                            Log.Info(string.Format("Received connection from: {0}", receivedResults.RemoteEndPoint));
                            Log.Info(string.Format("{0} - received [{1}]", DateTime.Now, String.Join("", data.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")).ToArray())));

                            var reader = new ReverseBinaryReader(new MemoryStream(data));

                            // Decode data
                            var avlData = new DataDecoder(reader).DecodeUdpData();

                            // Create response
                            var bytes = new List<byte>();

                            const short packetLength = 2 /* Id /+ 1 / Type / + 1 / Avl packet id /+ 1 / num of accepted elems */;
                            bytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(BytesSwapper.Swap(packetLength)));
                            bytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(BytesSwapper.Swap(avlData.PacketId)));
                            bytes.Add(avlData.PacketType);
                            bytes.Add(avlData.AvlPacketId);
                            bytes.Add((byte)avlData.AvlData.DataCount);

                            var response = bytes.ToArray();

                            Log.Info(string.Format("{0} - response [{1}]", DateTime.Now, String.Join("", bytes.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")).ToArray())));

                            await udpClient.SendAsync(response, response.Length, receivedResults.RemoteEndPoint);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                }

            });
            
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

my configurations setting app.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
    </configSections>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="ipAddress" value="198.199.67.142"/>
        <add key="port" value="777"/>
        <!--<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>-->
    </appSettings>

    <log4net>
        <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender" Target="Console.Error">
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%logger - %message%newline"/>
            </layout>
        </appender>
        
        <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="log.txt"/>
            <appendToFile value="true"/>
            <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
            <maximumFileSize value="500KB"/>
            <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%d %-5p %c %m%n"/>
            </layout>
        </appender>

        <root>
            <level value="INFO"/>
            <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
        </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

this is the error code i get, when I try to run it within linux ubuntu it returns this error:

```
   log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [Console] of type [log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender]. Reported error follows.
    System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'Kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libKernel32.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
       at log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender.GetConsoleOutputCP()
       at log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender.ActivateOptions()
       at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlElement appenderElement)
    log4net:ERROR Appender named [Console] not found
```

Please Help.

Comment: I suspect that this application was not originally written in `dotnet core`. Was this originally a `.Net` framework application? How did you migrate the code from the older application to the new application running on `dotnet` core? How did you attain the `log4net` library in your new `dotnet` core application?

Comment: If initially it was written in net framework 4.7 to migrate create a project from scratch selecting net core 3.1 as framework then copy the codes that are sockets and install from nuget what is necessary to make it work, would you like to see the original application?